# How to open a cmd inside the Java program and run the main function inside it

Tags: java, command-line, process

I can open a cmd like this with any command:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start command", null, new File(newDir));
```

Or other command similar with process,
How to open a cmd inside the java program and run the main function inside it, like this?

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe", mypackage.myclass.main,args);
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @tgdavies  I have a text app java and i want to not close  cmd quikly after run , but if i click on it jar file, it does,

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand any of that.

Comment: I have a Java text program and I want cmd not to close immediately after execution, but if I click on its jar file, it does.

Comment: Do you need to run this program in a separate window?  Is it acceptable for the output to appear in the calling program’s output?

Comment: @VGR I need exactly this: when I run , by clicking,  on the jar file of program, open one and only one cmd window and the function I want, for example, main, run inside cmd